# TestCafe: Uncaught ReferenceError: pagespeed is not defined

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

New to TestCafe.

**Expected**
Given .js below, expected behavior when running `testcafe chrome this.js` is to click on the header logo.

**Actual**
Uncaught ReferenceError: pagespeed is not defined (at the click below).

On our prod site, this error doesn't happen so most likely some configuration (possibly my version of Apache?) but I wanted to make sure there weren't any TestCafe specific issues.  Followed installation using the standard docs (npm)

Thanks in advance!

---

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture `A set of examples that illustrate how to use Little Passports`
    .page `https://xxx.xxdev.us/`;

test('My Company', async t => {
    await t.
        click('.header-logo');
});
```

---

I think I'll currently get around this by adding `-e`, but I'll keep this open just in case there's something else to consider...

Answer (score 1):

By default, a test fails when there is a JavaScript error on page. The "[-e (--skip-js-errors)](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/command-line-interface.html#-e---skip-js-errors)" parameter  allows running tests by skipping this JS error.

To check if there are any errors on your page, open your browser console. If there are any, you can either fix the errors at the application level (a preferable approach) or skip them during test run using the "-e" parameter.